# Paramiko EOF during negotiation for one particular desktop in LAN

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, cygwin, paramiko

There are two desktops in my network in both of which I have installed Cygwin and started sshd service. Using paramiko I am successfully sending and receiving files through sftp with one computer. But with the other I am getting the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Neptune_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\TC-Regression\netadmin.py", line 37, in <module>
    tc.receive_file_from_desktop()
  File "C:\Neptune_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\Common/shared\testCaseBase.py", line 258, in receive_file_from_desktop
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 379, in open_sftp
    return self._transport.open_sftp_client()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 811, in open_sftp_client
    return SFTPClient.from_transport(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 132, in from_transport
    return cls(chan)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 101, in __init__
    raise SSHException('EOF during negotiation')
**paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: EOF during negotiation**
```

The code running for both the machines is definitely same which is given below:

```
  ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
  ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

  try:

   ssh.connect(self.ftpipaddress,username = self.ftpuserName,password = self.ftppwd)
   #sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(trans) //Tried this too, did not work
   sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
```

I am thinking about the possibilites:

1. Cygwin sshd is not running properly on the failing machine. Though, when I open Cygwin I get the same output below for both the machines:

> $ cygrunsrv --verbose -Q sshd

```
Service             : sshd
Display name        : CYGWIN sshd
Current State       : Running
Controls Accepted   : Stop
Command             : /usr/sbin/sshd -D
stdin path          : /dev/null
stdout path         : /var/log/sshd.log
stderr path         : /var/log/sshd.log
Environment         : CYGWIN="ntsec"
Process Type        : Own Process
Startup             : Automatic
Dependencies        : tcpip
Account             : .\cyg_server
```

2. I am checking Windows Firewall in the failing machine. But unable to find any blocking process for port 22. I also set a new rule but that also did not help. Do I need to check anything further in Windows firewall?

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem? It might be due to differences in the server-side implementation of SSH. Paramiko seems to have issues with some implementations while working fine with others.